# Given a square $\gamma$ with vertices at $\pm 2,\pm2i$ Calculate $\int_{\gamma}\frac{z}{\sqrt{1+z+z^4}}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Given a square $\gamma$ with vertices at $\pm 2,\pm2i$, evaluate the following integral

$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{z}{\sqrt{1+z+z^4}}dz$$

I know that I can look at a circle with radius 2 and center at 0 which encloses the square and I want to see what the transformation $(1+1/z^3+1/z^4)$ does to the circle.

Comment: A cube? Sure about that?

Comment: Yea this is from a test

Comment: It really looks like a square to me.

Comment: Personally I would have said "octahedron"; a 2-d "cube" has its vertices at $\pm 1\pm i$.

Comment: I will change from cube to square if this is bothers you

Comment: I think the countour holds all the singularities of the integrand, and because of the square root the residue will be 0 for all of them. So by the residue theorem the integral shall be zero.